# Work arounds for access to public SVN projects behind a proxy?

Tags: svn

At work our proxy server blocks all out going connections apart from HTTP commands. Even then most of them are blocked apart from the obvious (POST, etc.) This makes it nigh on impossible to checkout web based public SVN projects. Does anyone have any suggestions (yes my proxy settings are setup to use the company proxy!) that provide a way to do this? I have tried tunneling in to my machine at home to no avail.
Cheers
Chris

Comment: Ah, a poxy proxy. Does it support the CONNECT verb?

Comment: I believe that's denied but I'm not 100% sure. Could you suggest a way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Use secure **https://** protocol instead of http://.